# Jigoshop - only displaying 10 products

Tags: categories

Just wondering if anyone knows why Jigoshop will only display 10 products that I have in each category.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use this short code :

```
[jigoshop_category slug="yourcategory" per_page="10" pagination="yes"]
```